# SVN Externals and Permissions in the absence of path based access control

Tags: svn, version-control, access-control, authz

We are using SVN externals to basically create symbolic links to other repositories.
For example

```
svn://Repo1/Projects/Project1/Trunk
```

Contains some directories which are actually externals linking to

```
svn://Repo2/Projects/Derp_Library_Foo
```

When a user who only really needs access to **Repo1** and the few externals linked in **Repo2**, we are forced to **give full access to Repo2** otherwise they cannot checkout the path which contains externals to Repo2.
If we use path-based access control, we could easily create groups to manage this, but right now it is black or white: full access to the repo or none.

Is there any solution that doesn't involve using path-based access and doesn't involve duplicating the shared data/libraries?
We have SVN 1.6.11 using svnserve on Linux.

Comment: You could give those that only need to read from Repo2 read only access.

Comment: what language/tooling are you using?  svn:externals as a poor man's dependency management system is often the source of confusion and problems.

Comment: C/C++ Visual Studio mostly.  There is .net VB C# Java and other stuff too, but mostly C++.

Answer (score 0):

You have to grant **RO access only** to Repo2 in order to give user ability to checkout data from Repo1 with externals in Repo2